# I want to set the height in a Javascript code

Tags: javascript

I use the following code in my website which I found on cryptocompare.com:

```
baseUrl = "https://widgets.cryptocompare.com/";
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var embedder = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];
(function (){
    var appName = encodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname);
    if (appName == ""){appName = "local";}
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    var theUrl = baseUrl + 'serve/v1/coin/feed?fsym=BTC&tsym=USD';
    s.src = theUrl + (theUrl.indexOf("?") >= 0 ? "&" : "?") + "app=" + appName;
    embedder.parentNode.appendChild(s);
})();
```

How can I increase the height of the news section to 3000px, and how can I increase the width to 900px?

I tried adding `.setAttribute("style","height:3000px");` 
after the 3rd line but that didn't work.

Comment: You want to set the height of what ?

Comment: What is the html layout that this script is attached too?

Comment: I want to set the height of the news section. The code can be found here:

[link](https://www.cryptocompare.com/dev/widget/wizard/?type=5&theme=0&fsym=BTC&tsym=USD&feed=all).


Regarding the html layout, I'm not a developer so I'm not sure but I only copied that code to my wordpress site and it works fine except that I want to increase the height from 300px to 3600px.

Comment: It seems that you are implementing a 3rd party source code and this opens a div or an iframe on your webpage, you should check what is the element that your script is rendering than to imply the height on this element.

Comment: arielb, I'm not sure how to do that because I'm not a developer. Maybe you can tell me what to do?